# Woocommerce products query - order_by

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am using a query in my template.php file to display `wooCommerce` products by category.

My query looks like this:

```
<?php
   $args = array(
     'post_type' => 'product',
     'stock' => 1,
     'posts_per_page' => 99,
     'tax_query' => array(
          'relation' => 'OR',
           array(
              'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
              'field' => 'slug',
              'terms' => 'system_components',
              'menu_order' => 'asc'
           ),
           array(
              'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
              'field' => 'slug',
              'terms' => 'add-ons',
              'menu_order' => 'asc'
           )
      ),
      'meta_query' => array(
            array(
               'key'       => '_visibility',
               'value'     => 'hidden',
               'compare'   => '!='
      )
    ));


   $loop = new WP_Query($args);
   if ($loop->have_posts()) {
     while ($loop->have_posts()) :
          $loop->the_post(); ?>
            .....
```

This works, and I can see the products I want and the one I don't want are not visible.

The only bit I don't understand is that `'menu_order' => 'ASC'` doesn't seem to work.

I doesn't' matter what I type as menu order in the product settings, the order doesn't change.

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove `'menu_order' => 'asc'` part from `tax_query` and add to main, that should work:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'stock' => 1,
    'posts_per_page' => 99,
    'orderby' => 'menu_order',
    'order' => 'ACS',
    'tax_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        array(
              'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
              'field' => 'slug',
              'terms' => 'system_components'
        ),
        array(
              'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
              'field' => 'slug',
              'terms' => 'add-ons'              
        )
    ),
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key'       => '_visibility',
            'value'     => 'hidden',
            'compare'   => '!='
        )
    ));
```

As you can see in the [documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query), the `tax_query` hasn't parameter `menu_order`.

Comment: I moved it, like you suggested...but now I have something odd going on...
basically, only the first product is displayed? I only have one now...ideas?

Comment: Yeah, we missed `orderby` parameter, my bad :) See the updated answer.

Comment: Ok, they are all back now :)
Another quick question: I have two category, can I easily say something like "system_components" always before "add-ons"?

Comment: Do you mean ordering wp_query results?

Comment: in my tax_query i'm gettig two categoryes from the db, i'd like to alway show the system components first, regardless of the menu order, and the all others

Comment: No, wordpress doesn't provide such functionality. I suppose you should do it either via PHP, or, more easy way, run two separate wp_query-s for each category.

Comment: Ok thank you, it was just out of curiosity. This will do for now. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Please, Set page order in your product.

For this go to Admin panel. Click on Products menu from left menu, Then edit product and set page order.

Comment: I know, I am doing this already like I said on my question "doesn't' matter what I type as menu order in the product settings"